# How to trigger onValueChanged on every Input key stroke in survey JS Angular

Tags: angular, surveyjs

### Currently onValueChanged triggers on (onblur), I want to trigger on every key stroke to call the API.
HTML

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="survey-container contentcontainer codecontainer">
          <div id="surveyElement"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


const surveyModel = new Survey.Model(this.formConfig)
    
surveyModel.onValueChanged.add((result, options) => {
         console.log('kkkkk: ', options)
     })
```

JSON Schema

{
'name': 'mocknumber',
'type': 'text',
'title': 'MockNumber',
'isRequired': true,
'placeHolder': 'Type Mock Number',
'requiredErrorText': 'This field is required'
}

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the https://surveyjs.io/Documentation/Library?id=surveymodel#textUpdateMode
survey property to the "onTyping" value:

```
{
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page1",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "mocknumber",
     "title": "MockNumber",
     "isRequired": true,
     "requiredErrorText": "This field is required",
     "placeHolder": "Type Mock Number"
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "textUpdateMode": "onTyping"
}
```